# unable to save to database when using javascript .change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript here which is supposed to show/hide a div based on a selection of a select box. When I try to insert it in the database it only inserts the last option (paypal).

For example if i choose a cash option it will insert a blank field in the database. While if i choose Paypal it will insert it.. same goes for the rest of the options. Only Paypal is being inserted.

(I apologize for both my bad English and my spaghetti code)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#payment").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="bank"){
                $(".box1").not(".bank").hide();
                $(".bank").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="cash"){
                $(".box1").not(".cash").hide();
                $(".cash").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="cheque"){
                $(".box1").not(".cheque").hide();
                $(".cheque").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="invoice"){
                $(".box1").not(".invoice").hide();
                $(".invoice").show();
            }
            else if($(this).attr("value")=="paypal"){
                $(".box1").not(".paypal").hide();
                $(".paypal").show();
            }
            else{
                $(".box1").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    .box{
        display: none;
      }
    .box1{
        display: none;

    }
    .income{ background: #fff; }
    .expense{ background: #fff; }
    .blue{ background: #fff; }
    .cash{ background: #fff; }
    .card{ background: #fff; }
    .cheque{ background: #fff; }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                 <select id="payment" name="payment_type" class="form-control" required>
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Payment Type</option>
                 <option value="bank">Bank Transfer</option>
                 <option value="cash">Cash</option>
                 <option value="cheque">Cheque</option>
                 <option value="invoice">Invoice</option>
                 <option value="paypal">Paypal</option>
                 </select>

            </div></div>

            <div class="form-group bank box1">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="text" name="transaction_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Bank Account" maxlength="40"  />
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="form-group cash box1">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="text" name="transaction_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Cash Amount" maxlength="40"  />
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <div class="form-group cheque box1">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="text" name="transaction_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Cheque Reference" maxlength="40"  />
                </div>
                
            </div>   

            <div class="form-group invoice box1">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="text" name="transaction_" class="form-control" placeholder="Invoice Number" maxlength="40"  />
                </div>
                
            </div>    

            <div class="form-group paypal box1">
             <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
             <input type="text" name="transaction_amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Paypal Reference" maxlength="40"  />
                </div>
                
            </div>
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual form element, just a series of inputs, so it's impossible to say what might be happening with your submit methodology. I would point out that a large part of your problem likely stems from the fact that all of your input elements have the same name. Since the name attribute is how the form submit distinguishes the different elements when it gets the data server side, what's happening is all of your previous data is being overwritten by your last-defined element named 'transaction_amount'

Comment: I tried to insert the php in the snippet but it didnt work, I was thinking the name element too.. would an array work if I don't want to use different names?

Comment: You need to use different names for each input element, or the browser will just overwrite everything. If you don't want five different variations on 'transaction_amount', maybe consider using one input field, and then a radio button set or some such for the payment type?

Comment: Alternatively, you have the payment type in the select already. Just send that and the amount

Comment: This was exactly the problem, I will stick to your 2nd suggestion and add more custom fields for each different option. Thank you Ryan!

Comment: I can jam that comment into a quick answer, and you can go ahead and select that as correct so it will close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in having all of your input fields named the same thing. This is going to confuse the php script on the server side, because the input name is how it differentiates values. You might wan to try just having a single input field for the transaction amount and indicating the payment in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

When you use style `display: none` you only hides input. It is still send on submit. Paypal is the last so the last value is nothing because you didn't write anything in hidden input. You must change names of inputs to be individuals.